# Nature of interaction of two magnetic dipoles

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole, conservative-field

Is the force of interaction between two magnetic dipoles a conservative force? If not, how do we find that force?

Comment: Well you can determine the field of each dipole and use this to determine the force https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles

Comment: This question could be answered with one word: **yes**.